# Graphics Event List not showing my draw function

Tags: visual-studio-2012, directx-11, slimdx

I'm using SlimDX with Visual Studio 2012 and trying to debug my shader file. My Graphics Event List is not showing my draw call at all. The captured frame in the frame list shows black even though my image clearly is being drawn in the application. Everything else is there in the Graphics Event List. Just no Draw function.

Comment: What operating system and Graphics card do you use? Also do you have some text showing on your swapchain (asking to press print screen) when you start graphics debugging.

Comment: Oh, thanks for responding. I've figured out my real problem without debugging, but it would be nice to know how to fix this for future reference. But my job is closed for snow today, so I can't check there to answer all your questions. However, while I'm here, I may as well ask this. Is there a way I can use HLSL to keep track of what points I've already rendered so I can do some collision detection? I need to be able to eliminate city names as I zoom out of my map and the names start to collide. I've done it in C#, but it seems to me that HLSL would be more efficient, if it were an option.

Comment: Idea is to not draw quads as soon as one overlap with each other? Yes that's relatively easy and good job for either stencil/appendbuffers (if you run on feature level 11 of course)

Comment: Not exactly. See, I'm sending the text as a series of sprite coordinates (each letter is a "sprite") to the geometry shader which then determines the bounding rect of each individual letter. What I need is to disable ALL letters in a name once ANY of those individual letters crosses paths with another of a higher population city.

Comment: That's surely worth another question, since comments are not so handy for this

Comment: As you wish:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26998166/collision-detection-in-hlsl-directx-11

Comment: And as for my original issue, it seems to have fixed itself. I'm really not certain what I could have changed to fix it, but it's working now.